# Implement Next Buttons skip row when blank

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Im trying to implement code to click next. Most of the examples I have seen seem to just increment to the next row. I have contiguous cells in Column A but some of the cells are empty and i would like it to skip to the next row with data instead of just the next.

I am working with this sample code but for the life of me can seem to get it to increment and skip blanks

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    ' Increment row number:
    lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1

    ' Show contents of new row in the form:
    txtName.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value
    txtPhone.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Please remember to mark your questions as solved if you get a suitable answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set rFound = Columns(1).Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(lCurrentRow, 1))

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        If rFound.Row > lCurrentRow Then
            lCurrentRow = rFound.Row
            txtName.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value
            txtPhone.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 2).Value
        End If
    End If

    Set rFound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer - i haven tried to implement your code yet i have tried with tims below but i cant get it to increment i will post a new question

Comment: @paulworthington , you should continue with your question here rather than start a new one.

Comment: ty brettdj - im still getting used to posting questions cheers

Comment: What can I say? If you don't try it, I cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    ' Increment row number:
    lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1

    do while Len(Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value) = 0
       LCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1
    Loop

    ' Show contents of new row in the form:
    txtName.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value
    txtPhone.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 2).Value
End Sub
```

You'll need something in there to stop it running off the end of the sheet...

Comment: Thanks for your Answer -  i have tried with tims below but i cant get it to increment i will post a new question