# Can't Increment Cmd Next

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is supposed to get the next record when a button is clicked in an input sheet.

My button is named CurrRecNew on sheet3 when I click it performs the code below but it doesn't appear to increment. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

The datasheet sheet 1 has cells starting in Row A3 and going down eg

A3 1     B3 a
A4 Blank B4 b
A5 Blank B5 c
A6 2     B6 d
A7 Blank B7 f
A8 Blank B8 g
A9 Blank B9 h
A8 3     B10 ...

```
Sub ViewLogDown()
    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim InputWks As Worksheet

    Dim lRec As Long
    Dim lRecRow As Long
    Dim lLastRec As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rlen As Long
    Dim lCurrentRow As Long

    lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set InputWks = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With historyWks
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
        lLastRec = LastRow - 1
    End With

    With InputWks
        lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1
        lRec = .Range("CurrRecNew").Value

        Do While Len(Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value) = 0
            lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1
        Loop
        lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow - 1

        .OLEObjects("tbRiskID").Object.Value = historyWks.Cells(lCurrentRow, 1)
        .OLEObjects("tbRiskContext").Object.Value = historyWks.Cells(lCurrentRow, 2)
        .OLEObjects("TextBox34").Object.Value = historyWks.Cells(lCurrentRow, 3)
        .OLEObjects("tbRiskEx").Object.Value = historyWks.Cells(lCurrentRow, 4)
        .OLEObjects("tbRiskCat").Object.Value = historyWks.Cells(lCurrentRow, 5)
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: From your sample data it seems column `B` doesn't have any blanks.  Why not find the end of *that* column instead of `A`?

Comment: Hi Chris - the user can use drop downs in all other columns. Only col A is suitable as a reference guaranteed to have a value

Comment: Could you give some more explaination and in a cleaner way what you dont find incrementing

Comment: Hi Niko - sheet 3 has a next row button on it. This code 
is  supposed to get  the next row when the button is clicked.
The sheet1 Row 1 starts at A3. When i click the down button
i would like it to go to the next row but skipping the blank rows 
so the next row will be A6. When you click next again the next row 
should be A8

Comment: The value of lCurrentRow dosnt increment - As you click the button next the value of 1CurrentRow should increase as you traverse down the sheet

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 just after the while loop?  You're just going back up one row...  Also, you should make sure to qualify all of your range references with the worksheet.  You have Cells() with no worksheet qualifier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement Next Buttons skip row when blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949999/implement-next-buttons-skip-row-when-blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very confusing, you are finding the lCurrentRow on the InputWks sheet but then setting the textbox objects to the lcurrentrow on the Historywks sheet???  You need to explain clearly what each worksheet does, which sheet you want to find the next row on etc.

I presume that the you are using the named range CurrRecNew to store the current row. And you are wanting get the current row on the historywrks sheet.  Therefore as far as finding the next row which is your actual question your code should look something like this:

```
    Dim rFound As Range

    '// History sheet
    With historyWks  
        '// Get current row, you need to correctly define the sheet name which contains the CurrRecNew Range.
        lCurrentRow = InputWks.Range("CurrRecNew").Value

        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(lCurrentRow, 1))

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            If rFound.Row > lCurrentRow Then
                lCurrentRow = rFound.Row
                txtName.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 1).Value
                txtPhone.Text = Cells(lCurrentRow, 2).Value
            End If
        End If

        '// Once again correct the sheet name here I guessed CurrRecNew was on the InputWks sheet
        InputWks.Range("CurrRecNew").Value = lCurrentRow

    End with
```

Comment: Hey Reafidy, thanks for your code. I was missing the line lCurrentRow = InputWks.Range("CurrRecNew").Value that held the value for the counter.  The range CurrRecNew stores the current row and then gets the rows of data from the Historywks sheet. The find works well but it only works for a couple of rows then it remains static. Cheers thanks for your help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: Its Working now with a few mods and help from Reafidy and everyone else. I was missing the counter reference and also the data was being retrieved from the wrong worksheet. Cheers all thanks

Comment: Hey Reafidy, Now that the loop works with rows that are "Not Nothing". Any Ideas how i would return the rows between the Not Nothing rows. Col A loops down ok but there is some data in the Nothing rows in columns F. G, H, I J

Comment: As an explanation my data worksheet has 15 columns on it. If you think of an order form with order detail lines. The first 5 columns are the order and then columns 6-15 are the order lines - variable number. What i am trying to retrieve is the order and its associated order lines. eg Row 1 - col A to E are the order and the order detail Col F - O but Col F- O can repeat until the next order. Hope this explanation helps

Comment: @Paul, glad I could help. If the answer provided was an acceptable solution then you should mark it as the accepted answer and/or upvote if helpful. This ensures that no one else begins work on a question that has already been answered and that reputation is awarded to the appropriate members.  If you don't do this other members will be reluctant to help you. If you have new requirements as stated above please start a new question.  I will be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Reafidy - Omg i have been hunting all over the faq to find out how to mark it resolved. I just saw the tick next to the question doh. oops

Comment: Hi Paul,  no problem at all,  I should have explained how to do it.  Glad you have it sorted.  I will upvote to help you get started.  Cheers.

Comment: Hi Reafidy, thanks for your help, i really appreciate it. I feel like such a noob. The faq has info relating to how to ask questions but nothing in relation to how to mark the answer as accepted. Cheer mate have a great day